# Windows Phone local toast notification Text wrapping and image is not showing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, toast

In my application, sending toast notification from the application itself.

```
    ToastTemplateType toastTemplateXml = ToastTemplateType.ToastText03;
    XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplateXml);              

    XmlNodeList toastTextAttributes = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
    toastTextAttributes[0].InnerText = "Welcome to My app! Let us know how you heared about us.";
    string text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    toastTextAttributes[1].InnerText = text;
    ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

And in the [document](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/trycatchfinally/archive/2013/03/07/windows-store-app-toast-notification-templates-javascript-c-push-notifications.aspx) it shows

**ToastText03**

> One string of bold text wrapped across the first and second lines, one
>   string of regular text on the third line.

But when it shows, The first line is not wrapping at all and it lost it's tail part.

What I need to display full first line of the toast notification?

Comment: Can we provide local toast notification when app is running ?

Comment: @Eldho yes . We can do it by the way I described in the question.

Comment: Note  In Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1, a toast is not displayed if the current foreground app is the caller of the `ToastNotifier.Show` method. In that case, toast should primarily be used by a background agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way around this. Windows Phone 8.12 supports only the [toastText02](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.notifications.toasttemplatetype.aspx) template. This template displays the app's logo along with two strings on the same line, with the first string bold.

See the [toast template catalog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh761494.aspx) for details and an example image.

Comment: That's too bad to hear :(